# unlock of unowned mutex windows debug build

Tags: c++, windows, mutex

I am trying to port my existing Windows code to common code that works for both Windows and Linux.
Replaced CRITICAL_SECTION with std::mutex. The code fails with the error: "unlock of unowned mutex". This happens only with debug build and not with Release build.

Here is sample code where the behavior is observed:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>


static std::mutex g_suCxioAccessLock;

int main()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(g_suCxioAccessLock);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    g_suCxioAccessLock.unlock();
}
```

Can you please help me understand why it fails in debug build

Comment: Use `locker.unlock()`. You handed the mutex to a `unique_lock`. Use it to unlock it (or  just let it leave scope; that is, after all, the point of scope-based locks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `std::unique_lock` is to lock a mutex when constructed, and to unlock it when the `unique_lock` goes out of scope. You can get the `unique_lock` to unlock the mutex early with `unique_lock::unlock()`, though this is an uncommon thing to need; otherwise you should let it do the unlocking itself. As your code stands, it unlocks the mutex manually with `g_suCxioAccessLock.unlock()`, and then the `unique_lock` tries to unlock it a second time after `main()` returns.

Comment: Why it doesn't fail in Release build?

Comment: It does "fail" in the sense of not working properly. But Debug builds include extra checks and error messages to help you find the bugs in your code, such as this check to tell you that you're unlocking a mutex which is not locked.

Answer (score 2):

The lock already does unlock the mutex when it goes out of scope. Your code effectively attempts to unlock the mutex twice, but [`std::mutex::unlock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock):

> Unlocks the mutex.
>
> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Your code has undefined behavior. Anything might happen and the compiler was just nice to make your code cause a runtime error in a debug build. In a release build the `mutex` might be removed completely by the compiler, because, sloppy speaking, the compiler "knows" that UB does not belong into compiled programs. Unlock the mutex only once.

Comment: @hythis what do you mean with "GCC does not follow the spec"? GCC may do anything according to the specification when the specification says that it is undefined behavior. Throwing an exception is a very kind form of undefined behavior

Comment: @hythis you cannot unlock the mutex twice. Attempting to do so is undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

`g_suCxioAccessLock.unlock();` will unlock the lock twice, you can remove it.